Is it possible to invoke a different version of an overloaded class operator based on whether the call is made from inside or outside the class?
I am developing quite a large Class whose objects require relatively costly validation if they are created by the public constructors, but for which the validation can be dispensed with for private constructors (since one can assume to be working with already-validated data).
In C++, is it possible to overload an operator (e.g. add or +) with the same signature in such a way that a different version of it is called from 'outside' the class (with input validation) and a different version is called from a member function (without the validation)?
For example, I'd like something like this:
class cBigClass 
{
...
public:
    friend cBigClass operator*(const int a, const cBigClass& C)
    {
        this->Validate(a);
        cBigClass B = this->ComplicatedFunctionActuallyImplementingMultiply(a, C);
        return B;
    }

private:
    friend cBigClass operator*(const int a, const cBigClass& C)
    {
        cBigClass B = this->ComplicatedFunctionActuallyImplementingMultiply(a, C);
        return B;
    }

private:
    void DoSomethingPrivately()
    {
        int a = 1;
        cBigClass C, D;
        D = a*C; // Calls 'private' version of * without validation        
    }
};
...
// Elsewhere, e.g. in main()
int a = 2;
cBigClass A, B;
A = a*B; // Calls 'public' version of * with validation

A naive re-definition obviously throws a compiler error (g++), even when one is made public and one private. Both versions of such a function essentially have to have the same signature - is there a trick / hack for something like this? I would really like to avoid re-defining the operator code since it would lead to a lot of duplication.

Write everything without validation, then wrap that class with validation for public use.

"In C++, is it possible to overload an operator (e.g. add or +) with the same signature in such a way that a different version of it is called from 'outside' the class (with input validation) and a different version is called from a member function (without the validation)?..." No. D = a*C; and A = a*B; are doing the same thing/operation. So distinguishing between the two based on where they occur is just not possible.

"a different version is called from a member function (without the validation)" -- How do you know that the member function is called on an object that does not need validation (that was constructed by one of the private constructors, according to your logic)?

Short answer:  no.    For any given expression, the logic for resolution of an expression to function calls  (e.g. a = b * C becomes something like a.operator=(b.operator*(C))) is the same, regardless of where the expression occurs.   Access control (e.g. to prevent calling a private function by a non-member/non-friend) occurs after that.  The usual approach would be to provide private functions that can be called directly by a class's member functions (or friends) and provide a set of public functions which (optionally) do validation and call the private functions.

Wrapping validated data in its own class is another alternative, So you then have (private) friend cBigClass operator*(ValidatedInt, const cBigClass&). (Similar to gsl::not_null).

Thank you everyone for your very informative comments here. @JaMiT the internal logic of the Class guarantees by design that any operations handled by the 'private' functions have validated inputs, and the validation itself is quite expensive. It seems then that something like a wrapper class is the best way to go, although that would require quite intrusive re-factorisation of the code.

@jedynygucio "any operations handled by the 'private' functions have validated inputs" -- This is s a significantly different claim than saying that any operations handled by the 'private' functions have inputs from private constructors. Validating *this before invoking a private member is more believable than what you currently claim in the question.

@JaMiT I think this is semantics at this point, and a different issue to what I actually asked about.

Most problems can be solved with another level of indirection/abstraction.
You can define a base class which defines the core features as protected. Then you can make your class to derived from that base class and redefine those functions with your validation steps.
An example is better than 1000 words:
class Base
{
    protected:
        double multiply(double a, double b) // Only accessible for derived classes
        {
            return a*b;
        }
};

class MyClass : public Base
{
    private:
        void validate()
        {
            // Do whatever validation you want
        }

    public:
        double multiply(double a, double b) // User exposed function with validation included
        {
            validate();
            return Base::multiply(a, b);
        }
};

Live demo

Thank you for this suggestion. I was hoping to have to avoid a wrapper Class since it would be quite a lot of refactorisation.

I assume you meant to make double multiply a virtual method instead of just hiding the base method. The hidden base method will remain accessible when you cast a MyClass instance to its base type.

@Thibe It was not necessary for the sake of the example, but anyway, it's a protected member function so it won't be accessible from the outside world anyway (so the cast to the base type won't expose it)
